# How to trigger logout.php script without forms or Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I want to have a button, that logs out the user on click.
But I don't feel like creating a form for that, or making an "onclick" handler.
Is there another way to do it?

```
<p class='loginposition normal'>
."$_SESSION['email']".<form action='/logout.php' method='post'><input class='logout-submit button' type='submit' style='float:right;' id='logoutbtn' value='Log Out'></form>
</p>";
```

I want them to be in one raw:
user@user.com [Log Out]

Comment: You could use a get request to logout, but that would violate the principle that GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than data retrieval. If that's not a problem, just use a plain anchor element and style it like a button or whatever.

Comment: You have to use PHP to destroy session or else any one can access other peoples pages.

Comment: why not? probably there is a solution that use one of these methods and fit your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a POST request then you need either Ajax (which would be a silly technique to use for logging out) or a form.

Since logging out is not a repeatable action, POST is the correct tool to do it.

Get over your feelings and use a form.

You can deal with the twin problems of your HTML being invalid and additional line breaks by putting the paragraph inside the form instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to use either forms or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

what about this (you have to edit your logout.php): ?

```
<a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
```

Comment: The link could be automatically followed (e.g. by a precacher) and log the user out automatically. GET requests are unsuitable for this task.

Comment: @Quentin is that a realistic situation? even stackoverflow uses an `<a />` for logout

Comment: @rickyduck — Yes. Forum admins have deleted entire pages of forum posts that way. StackOverflow is not a shining beacon of best practises when it comes to web dev.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class='logout-submit button' type='button' style='float:right;' id='logoutbtn' value='Log Out' onClick='window.location.href="./logout.php"'>
```

the shortest way if you want to use a button i think.

Comment: as i said. it's just the shortest way ^^
if u dont want to use neither forms nor js or such, u proppably should handle it with a simple link

    <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>

as @silly said...

Answer (score 0):

...you could use a flash buttons which sends a POST request to logput.php if u're familiar with as3 / as2

Answer (score -1):

you could use ajax method of jQuery, something like this

```
$('#logout-button').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "logout.php",
    success: function() {
       alert("You have been successfully logged out");
       window.location.href = "home.php";
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Error! Something unexpected happened");
    }
});
return false;
});
```

I guess that would work...

Comment: as above, specifically stated no js